# How do you get the Kendo UI Barcode to render in Kendo Mobile app

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to figure out how to use a jQuery plugin with the Kendo UI template.

I have an index.html that calls a views/home.html file.  Then there is a home.js file that controls some functionality for the home.html using a model. 
I am trying to use a jQuery barcode plugin.  We are dynamically getting data from our service and outputting the data (although right now I am just trying to hardcode values).  How would I get the jQuery plugin to work with the Kendo UI template code.

My code is below.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/home.js"></script>

<div data-role="layout" data-id="main"> 
    <div data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <!--Need to add back button and mail center buttons-->
            <span data-role="view-title"></span>

            <a data-role="button" data-align="right" href="views/messagecenter.html" class="nav-button"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
           <a href="#left-drawer" data-role="button" data-align="right" class="nav-button" data-rel="drawer"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>

        </div>
    </div>


</head>
```

home.html

```
 <div data-role="view" data-layout="main" data-model="app.MemberInfo" data-title="Home" >
 <div id="MemberCardHeader">
    <div data-template="memberTemplate" data-bind="source: MemberInfo">

        <!--Member card x-kendo-template id="memberTemplate" renders here-->

    </div>
</div>


</div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="memberTemplate">
<div id="memberCard">
     <!--Barcode should render here-->
    <div id="Barcode"></div>
</div>

</script>
```

home.js

```
 var app = app || {};

 app.MemberInfo = (function (){

/*Barcode code*/
/*HOW DO I GET THIS TO WORK WITH KENDO UI CODE ABOVE*/
$("#Barcode").kendoBarcode({
    value:"288288",
    type:"ean8"
});

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can instantiate the widget in the init event of the view:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/view#events-init.

Comment: Hi Petyo,  so technically I don't have access to the DataViz using the Kendo.UI.All.js since my plan does not allow me to do this.  So we are looking at taking another route.  The issue is, we are pulling data using Kendo and a Model, outputting out data into a Kendo template script in the home.js. We found a jQuery plugin that generates a barcode from a number.  The issue is, I can't seem to get the jQuery and the Kendo template script to work together. Any pointers?